# Print Html page inserted in a php variable without header redirection

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a feature that insert data from csv file into database

I developped all things correctly , when a user import a csv file , I print the results in the admin page like this [file results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1U3C.png) .
But what I want is

```
// generate html file 
                $filetitle = 'Classes Importées à : ' . date('d-m-Y-H:i:s') ;
                $filename = 'classes_importées_' . date('d-m-Y-H:i:s') . '.html';

                $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8">
                                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                                <title>' . $filetitle . '</title>
                                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <style>
                                    table.csv-result{
                                        left: 50%;
                                        top: 50%;
                                        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                                        position: absolute;
                                        width: 50%;
                                        border-color: black;
                                        font-family: cursive;
                                    }
                                    table.csv-result th {
                                        text-align: center;
                                        padding: 20px;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        background-color: #00a79d;
                                        color: #fff;
                                    }
                                    table.csv-result td {
                                        text-align: center;
                                        padding: 15px;
                                    }
                                </style>';
                $html .=        '<table border="2" cellpadding="4" class="csv-result">';
                $html .=                '<thead>';
                $html .=                    '<tr>';
                $html .=                        '<th class="column-kwf-group-name">Group Name</th>';
                $html .=                        '<th class="column-kwf-group-slug">Group Slug</th>';
                $html .=                    '</tr>';
                $html .=                '</thead>';
                $html .=                '<tbody>';
                                        foreach (array_combine( $group_names, $group_slugs ) as $gp_name => $gp_slug ) :
                $html .=                    '<tr id="kwf-csv-example" valign="middle">';
                $html .=                        '<td class="column-kwf-group-name">' .  $gp_name  . '</td>';                                
                $html .=                        '<td class="column-kwf-group-slug">' . $gp_slug . '</td>';
                $html .=                    '</tr>';    
                                        endforeach;                                                         
                $html .=                '</tbody>';
                $html .=        '</table>';
                $html .=    '</body>';
                $html .=    '</html>';
```

this `$html` variable content be downloaded as separate html page without php headers redirection like this [wanted page format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/808iR.png), but when I did some tricks using php header or download using javascript I got this [unwanted page format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36WuQ.png)

How Can I acheive this ?
Note : this is a custom wordpress plugin I'am working on that insert data from csv file into database

here is the entire php file

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) 
    exit;


class kwf_classes_importer{
    function __construct(){   
    }

    # display admin page
    function admin_gui() {

        # check user capability
        if ( !current_user_can( 'publish_pages' ) )  {
            wp_die('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.');
        }

        # pre-setup
        $notice = '';
        $errors = '';

        # start import
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            global $bp, $wpdb, $group_slugs, $group_names;

            $group_slugs = array();
            $group_names = array();

            # Check whether BP is active and whether Groups component is loaded, and throw error if not
            if(!(function_exists('BuddyPress') || is_a($bp,'BuddyPress')) || !bp_is_active('groups')) {
                echo 'BuddyPress is not installed or the Groups component is not activated. Cannot continue.';
                exit;
            }
            # pre-controls
            if ($_FILES['csv_file']['size'] == 0) {
                echo "It is a blank file";
                exit;
            }
            if ($_FILES['csv_file']['error'] != 0) {
                echo "Upload error";
                exit;
            }
            $info = pathinfo($_FILES['csv_file']['name']);

            if($info['extension'] != 'csv'){
                echo "Only csv file can be uploaded";
                exit;
            }

            # extract post values
            extract( $_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE );

            # load CSV file
            if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                # read 1000 lines per run
                $group_count = 0;
                $existing_group_count = 0;
                $i=0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                    if ($data[0]== '' || $data[1]=='' || $data[2]=='' || $data[3]=='') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    # get details from csv file
                    $csv_group_name = trim($data[0]);
                    $csv_group_invite_status = trim($data[1]);

                   /*  if(sizeof($data) != 9) {
                        echo "CSV file is not according to sample CSV file";
                        exit;
                    } */

                    $group_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes(esc_attr($csv_group_name));

                    $group_search_args = array(
                        'slug' => $group_slug
                    );

                    $existing_group = groups_get_groups($group_search_args);
                    //  var_dump($existing_group);

                    /* 
                    - format : group_name, members, group_type, parent_group_slug, instructor_emails

                            $data[0] = 'group_name' ;
                            $data[1] = 'members' ;  $csv_group_invite_status
                            $data[2] = 'group_type' ;
                            $data[3] = 'parent_group_slug' ;
                            $data[4] = 'instructor_emails' ;
                    */

                    # create group
                    $args = array (
                        'name'          => $csv_group_name,
                        'slug'          => groups_check_slug($group_slug),
                        'status'        => 'hidden',
                    );

                    if($existing_group['total'] > 0) {
                        $existing_group_count++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else {
                        $new_group_id = groups_create_group ($args);
                    }

                    # group created successfully
                    if (!empty($new_group_id)) {
                        $u = '<a href="'.bp_loggedin_user_domain('/').'" title="'.bp_get_loggedin_user_username().'">'. bp_get_loggedin_user_username().'</a>';
                        $g = '<a href="'.site_url().'/groups/'.$group_slug.'/">'.$csv_group_name.'</a>';
          
                        /** Changes **/
                        $args = array(
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => '_sync_group_id',
                                        'value' => $new_group_id
                                    )
                                ),
                                'post_type' => 'groups',
                                'pos_status'=> 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1
                            );
                        $bbgroupid = get_posts($args);
                        if( !empty($bbgroupid) ){
                            $ldgroupid = $bbgroupid[0]->ID;
                            
                            /** insert group type **/
                            $group_type = trim($data[2]);
                            if( !empty($group_type) ){
                                $gptypeargs = array(
                                                'meta_query' => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'key' => '_bp_group_type_label_singular_name',
                                                        'value' => $group_type
                                                    )
                                                ),
                                                'post_type' => 'bp-group-type',
                                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                                'posts_per_page' => -1
                                            );
                                $grptypepost = get_posts($gptypeargs);
                                
                                if( !empty($grptypepost) ){
                                    $gptypepostid = $grptypepost[0]->ID;
                                    $gptypeslug = get_post_meta( $gptypepostid , '_bp_group_type_key' , true );
                                    $termobject = wp_set_post_terms( $new_group_id, $gptypeslug , 'bp_group_type' , false );
                                } 
                            } 
                            
                            /** insert group parent **/
                            $groupsluf = trim($data[3]);
                                if( !empty($groupsluf) ){
                                    $getparent = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."bp_groups where slug='".$groupsluf."'");
                                    if( !empty($getparent) ){
                                        $gpparentid = $getparent[0]->id;
                                        $updategp = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix.'bp_groups' , array('parent_id'=>$gpparentid),array('id'=>$new_group_id) );
                                    }                                    
                                }                                  

                            // get all courses that have the $group_type category
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type'   => 'sfwd-courses',
                                'post_status' => 'any', // published
                                'numberposts' => -1,
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'ld_course_category',
                                    'field' => 'slug', 
                                    'terms' => $group_type,
                                    'include_children' => false
                                    ))
                            );
                            
                            $courses = get_posts( $args );
                            
                            /** insert course in the given group type **/

                            if( !empty($group_type) ){
                                foreach( $courses as $course ){
                                    $course_slug = $course->post_name ;                      
                                    $cid = get_page_by_path( $course_slug, OBJECT, 'sfwd-courses' )->ID;
                                    update_post_meta( $cid , 'learndash_group_enrolled_'.$ldgroupid , time() );                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                            /** insert leaders in the group **/
                            $csv_leadersemail = trim($data[4]);
                            $allldemails = explode( '##' ,$csv_leadersemail );
                            if( !empty($allldemails) ){
                                foreach( $allldemails as $ldeids ){
                                    $lduserids = get_user_by( 'email' , $ldeids )->ID;
                                    update_user_meta( $lduserids, 'learndash_group_leaders_'.$ldgroupid , $ldgroupid );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        /** Changes END **/
                        
                        # set invite status
                        groups_update_groupmeta( $new_group_id, 'invite_status', $csv_group_invite_status );

                        $group_count++;

                        $group_slugs[] = $group_slug;

                        $group_names[] = $csv_group_name;
  
                    }
                    else {
                        echo sprintf( 'Cannot create group %s, probably a temporary mysql error', $csv_group_name);
                        exit;
                    }// else

                } // while
                fclose($handle);
            } // if
            else {
                echo 'Cannot open uploaded CSV file, contact your hosting support.';
                exit;
            }

            if ($existing_group_count != 0  ) {
                $error = '<div class="error settings-error" id="setting-error"><p><strong>' .sprintf ( 'Total %d groups are already found with the same name.', $existing_group_count ) .'</strong></p></div>';
            }
            if ($group_count > 0 ) {
                $notice = '<div class="updated settings-error" id="setting-error"><p><strong>'.sprintf ( 'Total %d groups are imported.', $group_count ).'</strong></p></div>';
            }
           
            if ( is_array($group_slugs) && is_array($group_names) && !empty($group_slug) && !empty($csv_group_name)){

                $slugs ='<div class="updated classes-results settings-error" id="setting-error">';
                $slugs .= '<p>' . __('Here is a list of slugs for created groups', 'kwf-import') . '</p>';
                $slugs .='<table border="2" cellpadding="4" class="csv-result">';
                $slugs .=        '<thead>';
                $slugs .=            '<tr>';
                $slugs .=                '<th class="column-kwf-group-name">Group Name</th>';
                $slugs .=                '<th class="column-kwf-group-slug">Group Slug</th>';
                $slugs .=            '</tr>';
                $slugs .=        '</thead>';
                $slugs .=        '<tbody>';
                foreach (array_combine($group_names, $group_slugs) as $gp_name => $gp_slug) :
                $slugs .=            '<tr id="kwf-csv-example" valign="middle">';
                $slugs .=                '<td class="column-kwf-group-name">' .  $gp_name  . '</td>';                               
                $slugs .=                '<td class="column-kwf-group-slug">' . $gp_slug . '</td>';
                $slugs .=            '</tr>';   
                endforeach;                                                         
                $slugs .=        '</tbody>';
                $slugs .='</table>';
                $slugs .='</div>';

               
              // include 'download.php';

               
                //require_once 'classes-importer.php';

            /*  if($slugs) : */

                // generate html file 
                $filetitle = 'Classes Importées à : ' . date('d-m-Y-H:i:s') ;
                $filename = 'classes_importées_' . date('d-m-Y-H:i:s') . '.html';

                $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8">
                                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                                <title>' . $filetitle . '</title>
                                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <style>
                                    table.csv-result{
                                        left: 50%;
                                        top: 50%;
                                        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                                        position: absolute;
                                        width: 50%;
                                        border-color: black;
                                        font-family: cursive;
                                    }
                                    table.csv-result th {
                                        text-align: center;
                                        padding: 20px;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        background-color: #00a79d;
                                        color: #fff;
                                    }
                                    table.csv-result td {
                                        text-align: center;
                                        padding: 15px;
                                    }
                                </style>';
                $html .=        '<table border="2" cellpadding="4" class="csv-result">';
                $html .=                '<thead>';
                $html .=                    '<tr>';
                $html .=                        '<th class="column-kwf-group-name">Group Name</th>';
                $html .=                        '<th class="column-kwf-group-slug">Group Slug</th>';
                $html .=                    '</tr>';
                $html .=                '</thead>';
                $html .=                '<tbody>';
                                        foreach (array_combine( $group_names, $group_slugs ) as $gp_name => $gp_slug ) :
                $html .=                    '<tr id="kwf-csv-example" valign="middle">';
                $html .=                        '<td class="column-kwf-group-name">' .  $gp_name  . '</td>';                                
                $html .=                        '<td class="column-kwf-group-slug">' . $gp_slug . '</td>';
                $html .=                    '</tr>';    
                                        endforeach;                                                         
                $html .=                '</tbody>';
                $html .=        '</table>';
                $html .=    '</body>';
                $html .=    '</html>';

               // echo $html;

                ?>

                <?php
             
            }  

        } // if

            ?>

            <!--  # display admin page content -->

            <div class="wrap">
                <h3><?php _e('Classes Import', 'kwf-import') ?></h3>
                <?php  
                echo $error;
                echo $notice;
                echo $slugs;

                ?>
                <p><?php _e('This plugin imports kodingschools classes with their settings from a CSV file.', 'kwf-import') ?></p>
                <p><?php _e('Prepare CSV file, and then click import. That is all, enjoy', 'kwf-import') ?></p>
                <h3><i><strong><?php _e('Notes :', 'kwf-import') ?></strong></i></h3>
                <ul style="list-style: inside;">
                    <li><?php _e('CSV file structure must match with the sample.', 'kwf-import') ?></li>
                    <li><?php _e('If you get "Request timeout" or similar timeout message while trying to import large CSV file contact your hosting support or split your files into two or more part.', 'kwf-import') ?></li>
                </ul>
               <form method="POST" id="kwf_importer_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><th><label for="csv_file"><?php _e('Choose CSV File :', 'kwf-import') ?></label></th>
                        <td><input type="file" id="csv_file" name="csv_file" size="25"></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'kwf-security', 'security' ); ?>
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="<?php _e('Start Import', 'kwf-import') ?>"></p>
                
                </form>
                <h3><i><strong><?php _e('CSV Sample', 'kwf-import') ?></strong></i></h3>
                <table class="csv-sample form-table" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="column-kwf-group-name"><code>[Group Name]</code></th>                        
                                <th class="column-kwf-members"><code>[members]</code></th>
                                <th class="column-kwf-group_type"><code>[group_type]</code></th>
                                <th class="column-kwf-parent_group_slug"><code>[parent_group_slug]</code></th>
                                <th class="column-kwf-instructor_emails"><code>[instructor_emails]</code></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="kwf-csv-example" valign="middle">
                                <td class="column-kwf-student-name"><code>Test group</code></td>                                
                                <td class="column-kwf-members"><code>members</code></td>
                                <td class="column-kwf-group_type"><code>410</code></td>
                                <td class="column-kwf-parent_group_slug"><code>ce4</code></td>
                                <td class="column-kwf-instructor_emails"><code>instructor1@email.com##instructor2@email.com</code></td>
                            </tr>                                                               
                        </tbody>
                </table>

                <p>
                    <?php _e('For downloading sample.csv file for classes, click', 'kwf-import') ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo plugins_url( '../samples/classes-sample.csv', __FILE__  ); ?> "><?php _e('Here', 'kwf-import') ?></a>
                </p>
                <?php 
                    
                  ?>
            </div>
        <?php   
    
    }

       


}// end kwf_classes_importer class

$kwf_classes_importer = new kwf_classes_importer();

?>
```